# Replace Single Quotes in Javascript String Support UTF-8

Tags: javascript

In my web application I get data from Instagram. Some full names have single quotes like:

> ♠ فال ورق ' تاروت ' پیشگویی

I'm trying to remove or replace them with an empty character, this code doesn't work and I can't replace them:

```
.replace(/("|')/g, "")
```

or

```
.replace(/["']/g, "")
```

How can I change this code to remove the single quotes?

Comment: Works for me: `console.log("♠ فال ورق ' تاروت ' پیشگویی".replace(/['"]/g, ""))`. Copy and paste that into a browser console and it works fine.

Comment: Why do you want to remove them? Is escapting no option?

Comment: @Pilan how can i escape them?

Comment: Use the [`escape()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp) function

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how you are testing this (in a [mcve]) and what leads you to believe it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution? Hope it helps!

```js
console.log("فال ورق ' تاروت ' پیشگویی".replace(/'/g, ""));
console.log("code'123".replace(/'/g, ""));
```

Comment: How is this better than what they already have (which removes double quotes as well)?